# Create S3_Backend Automatically after Creating S3 Bucket is that possible on Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i tried to use depend_on on other module to automate configure the backend for my terraform,tfstae after creating a bucket :

```
module "s3_module" {
  source = "./module/S3"
}


# module "s3_backend" {
#   source = "./module/S3_backend"
#   depends_on = [ module.s3_module ]
# }
```

but it didnt work and i got a message below:

Warning: Backend configuration ignored
│
│   on module\S3_backend\s3_backend.tf line 9, in terraform:
│    9:     backend "s3" {
│
│ Any selected backend applies to the entire configuration, so Terraform expects provider
│ configurations only in the root module.
│
│ This is a warning rather than an error because it's sometimes convenient to temporarily call
│ a root module as a child module for testing purposes, but this backend configuration block
│ will have no effect.

and there is a way to automate this ?

Comment: There are different ways of creating resource with a local state and then reconfiguring the backend to use a remote state. But I don't think this is the way it can be done though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't create both the backend and actual resources at the same time. To use s3 as the backend. We have to create the backend s3 bucket separately. There are multiple ways to create an s3 bucket(aws cli, aws console, aws cdk, cloudformation, terraform with local backend, etc)

Once the s3 bucket is created, configure it as a terraform backend for actual resource creation.

In general, the backend should be created before we run `terraform init` for actual resource creation.